# QDialog not centered on parent QMainWindow on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: qdialog, pyside6, qt6, ubuntu-22.04

I encountered a strange situation on Ubuntu 22.04, using PySide6 when spawning a QDialog from a QMainWindow parent via menu action, like with the sample code below:

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QDialog
from PySide6.QtGui import QAction

class Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QDialog.__init__(self, parent)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 500, 500)

        menu = self.menuBar()
        submenu = menu.addMenu("Submenu")
        self.action_open_dialog = QAction("Open Dialog", self)
        self.action_open_dialog.setCheckable(False)
        self.action_open_dialog.triggered.connect(self.open_dialog)
        submenu.addAction(self.action_open_dialog)

    def open_dialog(self):
        dialog = Dialog(self)
        dialog.exec()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication()
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    app.exec()
```

The position of the dialog should be centered on the main window as parent, according to the documentation, but this is not the case. In fact, the dialogs initial position can even be outside the main window when the latter is moved before spawning the dialog, and appears to be located at some fixed screen position on the upper left. Curiously, the dialog is properly appearing in the center of the main window when executing on a Windows system.

Is this a known issue with Linux systems and is there some way to force the dialog to appear in the main windows center?

PS: The Ubuntu OS is executed as a VM on VirtualBox, in case this is relevant.

PPS: As requested, the exact Ubuntu version is 22.04.1 and the Wayland (ie. mutter) version is 42.0-3ubuntu2 - this is really just a stock install straight from the downloaded ISO without any modifications.

Comment: I can reproduce the same results.  It happens in modal and modeless modes This must be a bug... You should report it on their bug tracker...

Comment: Are you using the default wm? Consider that the wm in Linux can do whatever it likes with windows, even completely ignoring some of their requests about geometry. This might not be a Qt bug, but a wm issue, and might even be *by design*.

Comment: @musicamante I didn't know that either.... So the official Qt documentation is wrong on linux?  Is this just with python implementations or with C++ too?

Comment: @Alexander Not exactly: Qt *does* try to tell the OS that it wants a modal dialog that should be centered on the parent, but due to the asynchronous nature of window objects in Linux (and its "customizability"), the wm could override that, even with custom default geometries set by the user (if the wm supports it). That said, after some digging, it *seems* like it could also be an issue with Wayland, but I really know almost anything about it, so I'm not really sure about that. It would help to know the exact Ubuntu version of the OP and if it's using Wayland.

Comment: I tested on 22.04 ubuntu desktop.  The standard version that uses gnome I am pretty sure

Answer (score 0):

With Glade 3.38.2 "Centre on Parent" for modal ***popup*** gtkWindows works perfect in XORG, but not in Wayland.

In Wayland you have to select ***Toplevel*** as type under **Window Attributes**. With popup only *position* = mouse works.

As this is a Wayland problem, the same may be the case for QT.