# Qt 6.4.2 / PySide 6.4.2 window move() not working on Ubuntu Wayland

Tags: python, window, move, pyside6, qt6

The example below creates a window in the upper left corner and ignores the `move()` function on Ubuntu Wayland 22.04.1 or 22.10 with all updates installed. It works on Ubuntu X11, Windows 10 and other desktops.

Pyside 6.4.2 testcase (installed via PIP):

```py
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
import sys

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
mainwindow = QMainWindow()

# Window move does not work on Ubuntu Wayland, works on X11:
mainwindow.move(1000, 600)

mainwindow.show()
app.exec()
```

Qt 6.4.2 C++ testcase:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWidget w = QWidget();    

    w.setWindowTitle("Window Move");
    w.setFixedSize(300, 200);    

    // Window move does not work on Ubuntu Wayland, works on X11
    w.move(1000, 600);    

    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Reproducible with `PySide2`.

What could be the reason for a difference between Windows and Linux?

**Updates:**

- [PYSIDE-2190](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-2190) issue confirmed by PySide developers.
- [QTBUG-110119](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-110119) confirmed by Qt window developers, not willing to investigate further.
- The reason why the quality of the Qt documentation is below our expectation is that the Qt developers confirmed this issue on Wayland and are ignoring the request to update the documentation.

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/73744987/20914576.